# How might I get a user input and compare it against a "correct" user input withing a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, passwords

So I want to make a batch file, where it gets a user's input, and if the input is correct, then proceed. I have no problem with the "Proceed" part, but actually getting a user's input and using it as a type of "password," is a completely new concept to me, and, frankly, I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some if statement on checking within the batchfile like this.

```
IF "%1"=="yourPassword" goto :proceed
```

NOTE: NOT GOOD DESIGN FOR PASSWORD. but if your just validating other things like date or other input this would do.
for password, it would be best to proceed first and query to DB within the program.

If you need more samples, check it 
[here](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)